# How to migrate from siglestore to mariadb

Tags: mariadb, singlestore

I have looked in a lot of places and cannot seem to get some information on the matter. I am interested in migrating from singlestore to mariadb, but there doesnt seem to be any documentation on the matter, only to migrate to singlestore. Does anyone have any information on the matter or if you use singlestore you are stuck with it and cannot migrate to another DB?